# No results are returned when using Like in sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am having syntax issue with MySQL with PHP.

My code:

```
$q['item_desc LIKE \'%?%\'"'] = array($criteria);
```

but it gets translated to SQL Query:

```
SELECT `Item`.`id`, `Item`.`item_desc`, `Item`.`row_num`, `Item`.`shelf_num`, `Item`.`shelf_loc`, `Item`.`datetime` FROM `inventory`.`items` AS `Item` WHERE `item_desc` LIKE '%'10'%'"
```

I believe I need to get rid of the single quotes inside the `%`. How do I do this?

Comment: Why is there a double quote in there? Try `$q['item_desc LIKE \'%?%\'']` or `$q["item_desc LIKE '%?%'"]`

Comment: Please add your actual code. Are you using some library or framework? PHP mysql functions do not translate SQL.

Comment: Yes, I am using CakePHP framework. Below is the code for Search method. public function search() {
        $criteria = $this->request->query['criteria'];       
        $this->request->data['criteria'] = $criteria;
         $q["item_desc LIKE '%?%'"] = array($criteria);          
        $results = $this->Item->find('all', array(           
            'conditions' => array(
                $q
            )
        ));

        $this->set(compact('results'));
        }

Comment: The error message for above code: Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '10'%'' at line 1

Comment: Did you try removing the double quote??

Answer (score 0):

There is an un needed double quote in there.

Try

```
$q['item_desc LIKE \'%?%\'']
```

or

```
$q["item_desc LIKE '%?%'"]
```